# How to find power of a given number?

Tags: perfect-powers

65536= 4^8------( how can i find the base and power for a number.)

Now, if I am randomly given a number. Say, 4096 and I need to find a common base having some power. I mean a^n.
Where a is the base and n is its power. So, accordingly answer for above number shall be 8^4.

Can you please give me some trick to find such bases and powers for a given number
condition- Not to use factorization method or something which could be time consuming.

Comment: Does $4096$ _have_ to be $8^4$, or can it be $4^6$ or $2^{12}$ as well?

Comment: Note that the powers are generally not unique. For example, $65536=2^{16}=4^8=16^4=256^2=65536^1$. But a simple way to find a power (though surely not what you had in mind) is: For any number $n$, we have $n=n^1$.

Comment: The only way to do it without factorisation is to look for integer-valued logarithm ratios.

Comment: Since $65536=2^{12}$ **is** the factorization of $65536$, I wonder how a method (that results in anything better than a trivial $n^1$) could be less complex than factorization. Even if a method merely finds $256^2$, we see that repeating it with the much smaller input $256$ will ultimately end up with the above factorization with little extra effort.

Comment: See https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2077/1993

Comment: So, all the comments here mean I have to use Factorization.

Comment: @FaariaShaikh No, see J.G. ' s comment. PARI/GP has a function ispower(n) , which finds the power with the highest possible exponent (assuming the number is a perfect power). The function is very fast even for huge numbers, so surely does not use factorization algorithms.

Comment: @ Peter, can you please elaborate more. I mean you said about a function. So, can you tell me more about it.